# How to calculate PI in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, pi

I have to get the exact amount of decimal digits of pi, so I tried using this method:

```
require "bigdecimal/math"
include BigMath
input = 9
output = BigMath.PI(input).to_s
puts output
```

but instead of getting this as a result:

```rb
output: 3.141592653 # Which are the first 9 decimal digits of PI
```

I get this:

```rb
output: 0.3141592653589793238462643313830947690870926e1
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have 1 million decimals [here](https://www.angio.net/pi/digits/pi1000000.txt). Hope is enough.

Comment: _"I have to get the exact amount of decimal digits of pi"_ – are you looking for `Float::INFINITY`? ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since π is an [irrational number](https://www.mathsisfun.com/irrational-numbers.html), its [decimal representation never ends and never settles into a permanently repeating pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi).

Therefore, [algorithms for calculation of π](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Pi_algorithms) can find only results with specified precision.

[`BigMath.PI`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.3/libdoc/bigdecimal/rdoc/BigMath.html#method-i-PI) - is not an exception.

Parameter [`prec`](https://github.com/ruby/bigdecimal/blob/master/lib/bigdecimal/math.rb#L183) which we pass as a first argument, means precision (that is the number of accurate digits after the decimal point).

When we execute `BigMath.PI(9)`, we obtain a `BigDecimal` instance, which string representation is `0.3141592653589793238462643313830947690870926e1`.

If we look more closely at this string we can see `e1` in the end.

[Such notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation#E-notation) is common in math and it means:

[image: E-notation Image]

Hence, in our case

```
0.3141592653589793238462643313830947690870926e1
```

is the same as

```
0.3141592653589793238462643313830947690870926 * 10 = 3.141592653589793238462643313830947690870926
```

Since we passed `9` to `BigMath.PI`, we have [at least 9 accurate digits](https://github.com/ruby/bigdecimal/blob/master/lib/bigdecimal/math.rb#L17) after the decimal dot

```
3.141592653589793238462643313830947690870926
3.141592653_________________________________
```

(Actually, when we pass `9` to `BigMath.PI`, it returns more than 9 accurate digits after the decimal dot, but we should not rely on this fact. You can [try to compare](http://www.math.com/tables/constants/pi.htm) if you like).

And probably the last thing to mention: we can't just convert `BigDecimal` to `Float`, if we care about accuracy, because `Float` in general stores only 15 digits after the decimal dot.

So, if your goal is to be able to show π with an arbitrary number of digits after the decimal dot, you can use the following method:

```
require 'bigdecimal/math'

##
# Returns PI as a string with number_of_digits_after_decimal_dot.
#
def pi(number_of_digits_after_decimal_dot: 2)
  # Let's assume presicion equals to 2 as an example
  precision = number_of_digits_after_decimal_dot

  result = BigMath.PI(precision)
  # => ВigDecimal 0.31415926535897932384671233672993238432e1

  result = result.truncate(precision).to_s
  # => String 0.314e1

  # Remove '0.'
  result = result[2..-1]
  # => String 3141e1

  # Remove 'e1'
  result = result.split('e').first
  # => String 3141

  result = result.insert(1, '.')
  # => String 3.141

  result
end
```

If not, then, please, update your question to make it less ambiguous.

Comment: About half of the digits you're claiming are not accurate are, in fact, accurate for pi.  See http://www.math.com/tables/constants/pi.htm

Comment: @pjs Thanks for your observation. I have updated my answer. `BigMath.PI(9)` really returns more than 9 accurate digits after the decimal dot. 26 to be more precise.

Comment: `BigMath.PI(9).to_s('F')` gives you the floating point representation.

Comment: @Stefan: Using a more reasonable argument name (because a keyword argument name that long is insane, the whole function body can [simplify down to `BigMath.PI(precision).truncate(precision).to_s('F')`](https://tio.run/##XY2xCsIwFEX3fMWDDGmWCoKLo4PgIBR/IKTNa/rApvXlBfHrYwdBdLznwjlc@letjI9CjGB6igEHmv19N3uZjFJaKw03lMIpQ3cBn8FDFqYU4UkyQSpzj@yW0QWKJNn5Ubb90biwSKu0CjjCSs3KG860pCPsrQI4Ubxunba7fC/bCpc0eMEftrjcmLOxClOoa5H85zvY@gY "Ruby – Try It Online"); all that string slicing and manipulation is kinda pointless when `BigDecimal` directly supports what the OP needs.